# Why is the "maxLength" attribute in an XSD not restricting the number of characters returned?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have an XSD element defined as the following:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="string1500">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="1500" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This element is referenced in another XSD in the following way:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="bons3:string1500" />
```

(*bons3* references the same namespace in both XSDs.)

When a string of length 2000 characters is passed into the Description field in an XSLT, all 2000 characters are preserved even though the the restriction of 1500 characters was put in place. Am I setting the restriction wrong, or is there another way to ensure in the XSD that the maximum length of this field is 1500 characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT and XSD are two different things. XSLT 1.0 doesn't care about XSD, or any other XML schema language for that matter. XSLT 2.0 introduced an XSD aware extension, for which you have to find an appropriate XSLT processor, which may stop you from processing the XML; however, it will not auto-magically make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

XSDs don't affect the behavior of XSLTs.  If you would like to limit the length of a certain value in your XSLT, you can use

```
substring(Description, 1, 1500)
```

when you refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a schema-aware XSLT processor such as Saxon-EE, you can write

```
<Description xsl:validation="strict">
  ...
</Description>
```

and this will ensure that the content of the element is valid against the declared type of the Description element declaration in the schema. (The schema must be imported into the stylesheet using an xsl:import-schema declaration).